# University project on resume?

Tags: resume, applications

I have this project in my university where they ask us to create a working virtual computer using assembly language. I have 1-2 side projects that I am planning to include in my resume under 'projects' for when I want to apply for a job. I feel that this university project could be a nice third add on to that list that shows my skills are broader than just pure coding.

My question is that if this is a good idea and if it is even an acceptable project as it is technically given to me and multiple students as a requirement for the module.

Comment: This would likely fall under education.

Comment: Would this be your first job?

Answer (score 4):

Should be fine as long as you mention that this university project was a collaborative project whereas the others were solo projects.

The fact that it was a collaborative project could actually be a plus, too!

Answer (score 2):

**It is OK to put on a resume anything that might help you get the job.**

When I am reviewing resumes of recent graduates, a particular project can be a nice item to differentiate you from other candidates, especially if it is particularly challenging or relevant to the kind of work I want the candidate to do. It's more relevant if you have little work outside your studies, and especially if it demonstrates skills that would not be assumed by passing your course.

Comment: (Note: I am sometimes reviewing dozens of resumes for coop positions from the same university, and all of them tend to put the same projects on their resumes. That isn't helpful, but it also isn't a hindrance.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did that when I got out of college. I would say companies are expected to read about your school projects. Be ready to answer questions to it but not only on their success but failures and what sort of actions you did to correct it.